# MongoError: After applying the update to the document

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I need some help.

I'm trying to make post req to this route:

```
router.post('/admin/editFront', isLoggedIn, (req, res, next) => {
    req.checkBody('title', 'Title is require').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('aboutUs', 'About us section is require').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Check email again').notEmpty().isEmail();

    let errors = req.validationErrors();
    if(errors) {
        req.flash('error_msg', errors.msg);
        console.log(errors);
    }

    let cube = ({
        title: req.body.cubeTitle,
        img: req.body.cubeImg,
        info: req.body.cubeInfo
    })

    let front = new FrontInfo();
    front.title = req.body.title;
    front.aboutUs = req.body.aboutUs;
    front.email = req.body.email;
    front.phone = req.body.phone;
    front.cube.push(cube);
    // front.socialNet.push(req.body.social);

    console.log(front);

    FrontInfo.findOneAndUpdate({email: req.body.email}, front, { upsert: true }, (err, doc) => {
        if(err) console.log(err);
        else {
            req.flash('success', doc);
            res.redirect('/editFront');
        }
    });
});
```

Here is my Schema:

```
let cube = new Schema({ 
    title: { type: String },
    img: { type: String },
    info: { type: String }    
});

let socialNet = new Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    link: { type: String, required: true },
    icon: { type: String, required: true }
});

let FrontInfo = new Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    aboutUs: {type: String, required: true},
    phone: {type: String, minlength: 9, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true},
    cube: {type: [cube], default: []},
    updateDate: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

So, if I try to create a new Schema it works.
But if I try to update the new one I get this error:

[image]

I spent a long time trying to fix it!
Please help me friends

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `let front = new FrontInfo();` you are creating a new document that has its own `_id`. This `_id` is different from the `_id` of the document that you're updating. You are not allowed to update the `_id` field, which is why you get the error message

> the (immutable) field '_id' was found to have been altered to _id

So instead of creating a new Mongoose document you should just create a new ordinary Javascript object instead:

```
let front = {};
front.title = req.body.title;
front.aboutUs = req.body.aboutUs;
front.email = req.body.email;
front.phone = req.body.phone;
front.cube = [];
front.cube.push(cube);
```

This only contains the fields that you've listed.

Comment: Ok, Now my new problem is the cube edit the same one and not make a new one or if it is empty not make any push

Comment: @JohnYaghobieh Then you can probably use [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) and [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/). [This](https://pastebin.com/vABkrH2v) might work.